# JavaScript DevExtreme datagrid group footer

Tags: datagrid, devextreme

I am having datagrid where in i have a custom cell template for a particular column.
I have also grouped the data with a particular column and i am displaying group summaries for some column at group footer.

My problem is the column with custom cell template which i havent assigned any group summary shows the cell template at footer.
Please check the codepen link to know the problem

https://codepen.io/aasiph/pen/qYBVMd

```
$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: orders,
        keyExpr: "ID",
        selection: {
            mode: "single"
        },
        columns: [{
                dataField: "OrderNumber",
                width: 130,
                caption: "Invoice Number"
            }, {
                dataField: "OrderDate",
                width: 160,
                dataType: "date",
            }, {
                dataField: "Employee",
                groupIndex: 0
            }, {
                caption: "City",
                dataField: "CustomerStoreCity"
            }, {
                caption: "State",
                dataField: "CustomerStoreState",
            }, {
                dataField: "SaleAmount",
                alignment: "right",
                format: "currency"
            }, {
                dataField: "TotalAmount",
                alignment: "right",
                format: "currency"
            },{
                     caption: "",
                     allowGrouping: false,
                     allowFiltering: false,
                     allowSorting: false,
                     cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
                         $('<div><a href="#'+options.data.OrderNumber+'">View</a></div>')
                             .appendTo(container);
                     }
                 }
        ],
        sortByGroupSummaryInfo: [{
            summaryItem: "count"
        }],
        summary: {
            groupItems: [{
                column: "OrderNumber",
                summaryType: "count",
                displayFormat: "{0} orders",
            }, {
                column: "SaleAmount",
                summaryType: "max",
                valueFormat: "currency",
                showInGroupFooter: false,
                alignByColumn: true
            }, {
                column: "TotalAmount",
                summaryType: "max",
                valueFormat: "currency",
                showInGroupFooter: false,
                alignByColumn: true
            }, {
                column: "TotalAmount",
                summaryType: "sum",
                valueFormat: "currency",
                displayFormat: "Total: {0}",
                showInGroupFooter: true
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

I dont want the cell template to be displayed in group footer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
                    if(options.rowType == "groupFooter") return;
                     $('<div><a href="#'+options.data.OrderNumber+'">View</a></div>')
                         .appendTo(container);
                 }
```

if(options.rowType == "groupFooter") return; solved the problem. Problem was resolved through DevExpress support.